# Low level systems programming with C++

Tags: c++, systems-programming

I have been using C++ for a while now and I began to get interested in lower level system programming like drivers and stuff. Even some kind of primitive operating system could be very interesting project!

I have no clue where I could start. Are there any not-too-challenging things I could get started with and are there anything about C++ I should try to avoid like exceptions in performance critical code?

My current OS is Windows 7 if that matters much.

Comment: If you are building device-drivers and operating systems, you should probably avoid C++ exceptions. period.

Comment: This resource may not be too useful for you since you are on Windows, but MacOS X implements its drivers in a C++ framework call IOKit.  there is a lot of documentation on it at developer.apple.com

Comment: ever think about writing hypervisor code? https://github.com/Bareflank/hypervisor

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Writing Windows device drivers in C++ isn't impossible, there are not many CRT functions that you could use to get you into trouble.  The new operator is unusable for example, you don't have to fear a std::bad_alloc.  Unless you replace it, that cuts out a rather large swath of standard C++ library classes.

But that's not really the point of a device driver, it is rather important that you make it as small as possible.  C++ pays off when you write *complex* code.  You explicitly do *not* want to write complex code in a device driver.  Debugging it is redrum.

Linus really likes C in the kernel.  There's a good reason for that.

Comment: "Linus really likes C in the kernel" Can you explain what it means?

Comment: Google knows what that means, first hit is his opinion about C++.

Comment: Whoa, I've found it, quite funny.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't provide quite all of the tools you will need to actually implement a full operating system in it.  There are a few machine specific things that cannot be done in c++.  These things are handling and raising interrupts, controlling the MMU, controlling access to supervisor cpu instructions, and a handful of other small odds and ends.

Fortunately, these things are few enough that they can be written in assembly language accessed from C++.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [osdev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) (lots of questions that will pop into your mind when considering developing your own OS are answered here).

Comment: That site looks promising. I already found the biggest performance eaters I should avoid. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you start by hacking existing open source device-drivers and kernels, which you can really only do in Linux or *BSD. The experience will also give you a good sense of whether you're cut out for this kind of programming.

Comment: I sure will. Most if not all of those are in C, right? I'll probably learn a lot from them anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I have [heard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian_OS) the recently open sourced Symbian OS is written using C and C++.  Not sure which parts of it are done with C++ as I have not read the code base.  Consider looking into it.

Kerneltrap.org has some very good discussions about why the Linux kernel does not have C++ in its code base.  Consider reading that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Symbian OS is written in a variant of C++. Of course, there's assembly code for low-level things, but that is all wrapped up. You cannot use exceptions, and for real-time drivers you cannot do normal things like dynamic memory allocation, not even in C.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend **C Programming Language** and assembler. I'm not sure if it's possible to low-level much with C++.

Comment: In what way is C++ less capable for low level things than C?

Comment: Most code samples I have seen and compilers I have used were for C + assembler. I just wanted to say that low-level programming was easer to learn with C.

Comment: It's not that C++ is less capable, rather that it's less compatible.  Lots of in-kernel APIs assume/support only C-style code, and don't support C++ niceties (such as exceptions, RTTI, etc).  It's possible to do drivers and kernels in C++, but you have to really know what you're doing (and in particular what parts of C++ to avoid).  And if you're knowledgable enough to do that, you're probably knowledgable enough to just code in straight C and avoid the hassle.

Comment: yay! some c++ lover doesn't like me :D

Comment: @Jeremy, and yet the limited sub-set of C++ you could use *still* provides a lot of nice abstractions that are harder to implement or non-existent in C, such as data encapsulation, namespaces, and automatic initialization/destruction of objects.

Comment: @Charles, and almost my favorite, templates.